# Braintree braintree.dropin.create failed because of CORS

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm following the instructions from here https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3

When I try braintree.dropin.create I have the following error:

> https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/parameters
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not
>   equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I'm doing the call from JavaScript v3, from localhost.

The Braintree site doesn't have any information on this issue. Google search doesn't help either.

UPD. Found solution. The problem was I tried the example from the local static html file. As soon as I run a server website (Express) and copied the code there everything worked as expected.